# Pico.css + Swiper issue. Random blue square around my button that I can't get rid of

Tags: css, swiper.js

I'm using pico.css and Swiper to create a carousel. For some reason, there is this mad annoying ring that appears around my nav arrows.

I'm not sure how to get rid of. If I remove Pico.CSS to isolate the issue, the ring disappears so it's definitely pico.css. Does anyone know of a way to force this off or what components of a button it is?

[Annoying ring](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lQY2c.png)

I removed the background (big blue background), but the outline itself was not removed.
background: none !important;
outline: none! important; //does not work

Comment: Nvm found it

 .swiper-button-next, .swiper-button-prev {
        background: none !important; /* Override background */
        outline: none !important; /* Override outline */
            box-shadow: none !important;
            border: none !important;
        }